# Duplicates in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

What's an elegant way of handling duplicates in a Binary Search Tree? Let's assume each key will have several different values associated. What I need to do is iterate over all values in order. So if I had 2 values A and B with key 1, and one value C with key 2, I would like to get pairs: (1,A), (1,B), (2,C), when calling something like TreeIterator.next();

I can think of:

- Each node has a key, and an array of values where values with the same key go
- Each node has a `visited` flag

Any other suggestions? As a general guideline, i would like the Tree implementation to be as abstract as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "handling"? Do you want to be able to represent them or swallow them? Why would you need a key and an array of values - if the values are all the same, why not just keep a count for the number of values logically in that node?

Comment: Added more description. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like basically you *do* want a list of values for each key, yes. So the process of adding to the map is:

- Does key exist?

  - If so, add value to the existing list.
  - If not, create a new node in the tree at the appropriate point (as normal) and start with a list of one value

When iterating over the map, your general pattern is:

- Yield all values from the left node (smaller keys)
- Yield all values for this node - (key, value1), (key, value2) etc
- Yield all values from the right node (larger keys)

Of course, if you don't need to implement this yourself for learning purposes, you could use a ready-made multimap, such as [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [`TreeMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html). If you *are* implementing it for self-education, I'd start off by implementing a "normal" binary search map, and then going on from there.